# Creating Java UML Automatically in NetBeans 6.7

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I have three packages in NetBeans 6.7 that i want to generate a UML Class diagram automatically for. I have created the new Model by reverse engineering my project, but when i highlight all three packages under the 'Model' heading and select 'Create diagram from selected elements' i just end up with 3 green boxes. I can create separate diagrams by choosing the individual packages, but would ideally like a diagram that merged all three together. Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than just selecting the top level packages and hitting 'Create diagram from selected elements', expand the packages in the tree view and select the classes as well then hit 'Create diagram from selected elements'. That should show you the classes in the packages as well.

Comment: Thank you!! Don't know why I didn't think of that! Much obliged.

Comment: How do I now save this as a JPG or PNG image? When i select the diagram, the file menu's save options are greyed out...

Comment: @joec - double click to open the diagram. One of the buttons at the top (in the menu bar) looks like a little picture with an arrow coming out of it... That should do the trick.